# If the proof is correct, is there a shorter way?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I came up with this proof for the inequality. If the proof is correct, is it possible to come up with a shorter one? I feel like my proof is very inelegant and there is a short trick that can be applied.

---

Prove the following by induction (*B. Demidovich*, *Problems in Mathematical Analysis, §1, ex. 9*):

$$  \prod_{k=1}^{n} {(2k)! \gt ((n+1)!)^n, \ \ n\gt 1} \ \ \ (a)$$

Base case for n = 2 is trivial and boils down to: 
$$ (2!\cdot4!) = 48 \gt 36 = (3!)^2$$

Assuming (1) is valid for n, we need to prove:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} {(2k)! \gt ((n+2)!)^{n+1}, \ \ n\gt 1} \ \ \ (b) $$

I will rewrite the statement as:

$$(2n+2)!\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n} {(2k)! \gt ((n+2)!)^{n+1}, \ \ n\gt 1}$$

Using hypothesis (a) we see that it is enough to prove:

$$(2n+2)!\cdot((n+1)!)^n\gt ((n+2)!)^{n+1}$$

Let's perform equivalent transformaiton on the second term of the left side:

$$ (2n+2)!\cdot(\frac{(n+2)!}{n+2})^n\gt ((n+2)!)^{n+1} $$

Taking out $(n+2)$ from outside of brackets:

$$ \frac{(2n+2)!}{{(n+2)^n}}\cdot({(n+2)!})^n\gt ((n+2)!)^{n+1} $$

It is left now to prove that:

$$ \frac{(2n + 2)!}{{(n+2)^n}}\gt (n+2)! \ \ \  $$

Rewritten like this:

$$\frac{(n+2)!\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n} {((n+2)+k)}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n} {(n+2)}} \gt (n+2)! $$

Eliminating $(n+2)!$ on both sides leaves us with:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n} {((n+2)+k)} \gt \prod_{k=1}^{n} {(n+2)} $$

Which clearly holds due to $1 \le k \le n $. Therefore (b) holds. ∎

Comment: A shorter way is to skip for example some obvious steps you are taking but that probably doesn't count, in your opinion. A definitely shorter way is to use Stirling's bounds for the factorial parts.

Comment: @Eval Your proof looks correct to me. It doesn't have the issue I mention with the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this

$$(2n+2)!\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n} {(2k)! \gt ((n+2)!)^{n}(n+2)!}=((n+1)!)^{n}(n+2)^{n}(n+2)!$$

Since by hypothesis

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n} {(2k)! \gt ((n+1)!)^{n}}$$

You eliminate(see edit) those and check

$$\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+2)!}\gt (n+2)^{n}\Longrightarrow (n+3)\cdots(2n+2) \gt (n+2)^{n}$$

What is clearly true since each term at the LHS is bigger than $(n+2)$.

EDIT: just to be clear that here "eliminates" doesn't mean to cancel out factors, it means to assume a certain property so that we can check the remaining inequality. If $a>d$ and $b>c$ and all of them are positive$^1$, **we can conclude** $ab>cd$ by transitivity:

$$
a>d\Longrightarrow ab>bd
$$
$$
b>c\Longrightarrow bd>cd
$$
$$
ab>bd>cd\quad \blacksquare
$$

But from $ab>cd$ and $b>c$, we cannot conclude $a>d$. Just put $a=d$ in the first inequality.

$^1$ We also cannot use the transitivity above when factors' multiplication might change signal. Put $1>-1$ and $-2>-3$, clearly $-2>3$ is false.

Comment: If you're given that $a,b,c,d$ are positive quantities where $ab \gt cd$ and $b \gt c$, you can't conclude that $a \gt d$ as you've basically done. For example, try $a = 1$, $b = 8$, $c = 2$ and $d = 3$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan isn't saying that each term on LHS is bigger than each term on RHS sufficient for the conclusion? Or do you mean a different part of the proof?

Comment: @Eval In the answer above, for the equation I provided, the $a = (2n+2)!$, $b = \prod_{k=1}^{n} (2k)!$, $c = ((n+1)!)^{n}$ and $d = (n+2)^{n}(n+2)!$. I haven't yet checked what you wrote in your question, including how accurate it is and how this answer relates to it, but will do that now.

Comment: @JohnOmielan One question. Isn't it like he showed that $b > c$ holds by hypothesis and then proceeds to prove $a > d$ below, where he states that it is clearly true. So therefore $ab > cd$, which leads to ∎.

Comment: @Eval I misread what he wrote because he didn't repeat some info. from your proof. I see how that he means to prove the last line and then get back to the first one, rather than the other way around as it seemed to me originally. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @RickAlmeida Please ignore my original comment. As I stated to Eval above, I misinterpreted what you wrote.